# Recommended way to distribute Halide generated functions?

Tags: image-processing, llvm, software-distribution, llc, halide

I am currently experimenting with [Halide](http://halide-lang.org/), the initial tests show quite promising performance improvements.

I am now wondering about what is the best strategy to distribute Halide code. Requiring users to install Halide seems like a heavy barrier at this point in time (since there are no automated install options).

One option would be to use `compile_to_c`, add the generated C code in the repository, and distribute compilation scripts for such C code. [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) uses a similar strategy for Cython generated code. For Halide this seems like a no-go since the generated C code loses all the optimizations, defeating the purpose of Halide.

*My current idea* would be to use
[compile_to_bitcode](http://halide-lang.org/Halide/class_halide_1_1_func.html#af1766b2c9fe767ebe835b807db8b73cf), distribute the generated bitcode together with compilation scripts that call [llc](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) to generate the desired machine code. The only requirement for the user would be to have `llc` (i.e. `llvm`) installed.

Does anyone have experience on this issue?
What are the pro and cons of my idea of distributing bitcode?
What would you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some details on the kind of software distribution would help. The question implies a source code distribution, but there is a big difference between a library where programmers may need to interact with Halide produced code at a fine-grained level, and an application where use of Halide is largely invisible to the end user and the goal is just to get it to build.

Distributing bitcode is doable but problematic. To be portable, you have to use something like the PNaCl backend. (PNaCl is fairly close to a generic LLVM bitcode representation.) If you target a specific architecture, there is no guarantee the bitcode will compile or run on any other one. (Halide can lower to architecture specific intrinsics for example.) The LLVM community discourages using bitcode as a distribution format, though if it is in source form (.ll, not .bc) it is likely fairly stable and seems not much worse than shipping assembly files in terms of long term stability.

Halide includes an OS specific runtime into the generated output so even with bitcode, the result includes a number of target specific dependencies.

Often one ends up with a design that chooses, at runtime, between one of a number of Halide outputs based on the actual type of processor being used. E.g. using Halide to compile the same algorithm with two different schedules for SSE2 and AVX2 processors. In this model, there are going to be a lot of object files anyway and one can simply choose at build time which ones to include for a given architecture and OS. Distributing the objects as .ll files rather than .o files will likely work, but I'm not sure it buys much.

I would strive to make the full source code available, requiring Halide if one is doing a compilation from the ground up, and look for ways to provide various levels of binary distribution. Certainly for end user software the emphasis should be on how to get the fully built package into the hands of users. For libraries, Halide may be used to surface a higher level programming model to users of the library, in which case the Halide compiler will need to be present anyway.

We strive to make Halide fairly easy to get onto a system and very stable, but have not absolutely nailed either yet. I'd likely try to provide some level of fallback and using the C backend to generate generic C code might be a decent way to do that without rewriting everything in C directly. (If building from source, one gets a choice between installing Halide or using the prebuilt C code.) This is one of the better use cases for the C backend. (Generating C code from Halide is generally a pretty marginal idea despite it seeming to be a good one at first.)

Comment: So bottom line, bitcode is a bad idea. I will provide a compilation path without Halide too, and for fastest version thus Halide will be a requirement.  

Yes I was referring to an open source release of an application.

Answer (score 1):

compile_to_c() is definitely not recommended, as the code it generates isn't very optimized; it's useful mostly as a debugging / development tool.

compile_to_bitcode() sounds like it could work, but I'm not aware of anyone using this as a distribution method.

(It would probably be useful to have an automated install available for Halide.)